# Calculating stock quantity from multiple table transactions with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We had an issue with our stock whereby we had a balance column that would be added to or subtracted from whenever a transaction occurred.
There were some issues that we could not trace and hence have made changes whereby the stock would be calculated by adding and subtracting (where appropriate) the quantity moving and come up to today's stock value.

However now, the structure is such that one product has multiple stocks therefore product A with expiry 01/2012, 02/2013 etc.

I have currently created a query whereby for one stock of a product, it would calculate its current stock as follows:

```
select
(select ISNULL(sum(gd.qty),0) as grnadd from grns as g
INNER JOIN grndetails as gd ON g.id = gd.grnid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = gd.stockid
where g.locationid = 10 and s.prodid =2653)
-
(select ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0) as salesub from salesorders as co
INNER JOIN salesorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
where co.status != 'cancel' and co.locid = 10 and s.prodid =2653)
-
(select ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0) as cussub from customerorders as co
INNER JOIN customerorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
where co.status != 'cancel' and co.locid = 10 and s.prodid =2653)
```

Therefore in this case the stock is calculated for one product however can I make a query that would list all products with their totals (as above) in the second column?

Thank you and hope the structure is understood from the above query

EDIT:

Stocks Table: id, prodid, expiry

Products Table: id, tradename

GRN Details Table: id, grnid, qty, stockid (since its affecting the stock not product)

Sales & Customer Order Details Table: id, cusordid, qty, stockid

GRN & Sales & Cus Ord Table: id, locid

Locations Table: id, locname

Comment: Please provide table schema and some sample data.  Help us help you!

Comment: How to get location id for product? Location ID is provided as constant, so unless it should be 10 for each product you should tell us how to get it from product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to include all product-ids and group by it. here's some proposed code

```
select prodid, sum(total) as total from (
       (select s.prodid
             , ISNULL(sum(gd.qty),0) as total
          from grns as g
               INNER JOIN grndetails as gd 
               ON g.id = gd.grnid
               INNER JOIN stocks as s 
               ON s.id = gd.stockid
         where g.locationid = 10 group by s.prodid)
union all
       (select s.prodid
             , ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0)*(-1) as total 
          from salesorders as co
               INNER JOIN salesorddetails as cod 
               ON co.id = cod.cusordid
               INNER JOIN stocks as s 
               ON s.id = cod.stockid
         where co.status != 'cancel' 
           and co.locid = 10 group by s.prodid)
union all
       (select s.prod_id
             , ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0)*(-1) as total
          from customerorders as co
               INNER JOIN customerorddetails as cod 
               ON co.id = cod.cusordid
               INNER JOIN stocks as s 
               ON s.id = cod.stockid
         where co.status != 'cancel' 
           and co.locid = 10 group by s.prodid)
) as x
group by prodid
```

i have changed all the minuses to union-alls so that the product-ids will not get subtracted from each other and the grand total will be calculated respective to your product-ids.

Comment: Ah its prodid not prod_id and needed a group by for every inner union join.
Beautiful work, its working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH
    S AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT prodid FROM stocks
    ),
    L AS (
        /* SELECT 10 AS locationid */
        SELECT DISTINCT locationid FROM grns
    ),
    T1 AS (
        select 
            g.locationid, 
            s.prodid,
            sum(gd.qty) as grnadd 
        from grns as g 
        INNER JOIN grndetails as gd ON g.id = gd.grnid
        INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = gd.stockid
        GROUP BY g.locationid, s.prodid
    ),
    T2 AS (
        select 
            co.locid as locationid,
            s.prodid,
            sum(cod.qty) as salesub 
        from salesorders as co
        INNER JOIN salesorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
        INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
        where co.status != 'cancel'
        GROUP BY co.locid, s.prodid
    ),
    T3 AS (
        select 
            co.locid as locationid,
            s.prodid,
            sum(cod.qty) as cussub 
        from customerorders as co
        INNER JOIN customerorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
        INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
        where co.status != 'cancel'
        GROUP BY co.locid, s.prodid
    )
SELECT 
    S.prodid, L.locationid, ISNULL(grnadd, 0) - ISNULL(salesub, 0) - ISNULL(cussub, 0)
FROM
    S CROSS JOIN
    L LEFT OUTER JOIN
    T1 ON T1.locationid = L.locationid AND T1.prodid = S.prodid LEFT OUTER JOIN
    T2 ON T2.locationid = L.locationid AND T2.prodid = S.prodid LEFT OUTER JOIN
    T3 ON T3.locationid = L.locationid AND T3.prodid = S.prodid
```

I assumed that location might be also important, so it returns 3 columns. If you want results only for location with id 10, then in `L` CTL uncomment first line and comment second.

Comment: ran it and gave error:
Column 'salesorders.locid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
It also required prodid grouped by. However the SQL albeit good is quite difficult to modify as I have 10 tables to join to.
You touched the skies, I just wanted to traverse the land.

Answer (score 0):

assuming lots about your data model (hopefully i understood the question right), a `group by` might be the answer:

```
select
(select s.prodid, ISNULL(sum(gd.qty),0) as grnadd from grns as g
INNER JOIN grndetails as gd ON g.id = gd.grnid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = gd.stockid
where g.locationid = 10 
GROUP BY s.prodid)
-
(select s.prodid, ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0) as salesub from salesorders as co
INNER JOIN salesorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
where co.status != 'cancel' and co.locid = 10
GROUP BY s.prodid)
-
(select s.prodid, ISNULL(sum(cod.qty), 0) as cussub from customerorders as co
INNER JOIN customerorddetails as cod ON co.id = cod.cusordid
INNER JOIN stocks as s ON s.id = cod.stockid
where co.status != 'cancel' and co.locid = 10
GROUP BY s.prodid)
```

Comment: doesn't work as it specifies error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: yea my bad, i forgot to join them rather than having several sub-selects. See Brett's query above.